# How to color a curve

Tags: plotting

How does one color the interior of the elongated circular region in the following figure:

```
ContourPlot[y^2 - x (x - 1)(x - 3) == 0, {x, -2, 7}, {y, -4, 3}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without "==0"

```
ContourPlot[y^2 - x (x - 1) (x - 3), {x, -2, 7}, {y, -4, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: But I need only the curve not the surface

Answer (score 5):

Your plot

```
c = ContourPlot[y^2 - x (x - 1) (x - 3) == 0, {x, -2, 7}, {y, -4, 3}]
```

[image]
The region you would like colored

```
R = RegionPlot[y^2 - x (x - 1) (x - 3) < 0 && x < 2, {x, -2, 7}, {y, -4, 3}]
```

[image]

Both plotted together

```
Show[c, R]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much sir. That's what I need.

Comment: @Sara, You are welcome!

Comment: @Sarayaqob you mistakenly accepted  my answer

Comment: That's okay.  Anyway, your answer works.  One question is whether or not we can color in the round area only using `ContourPlot[]`.

Comment: You can color the `RegionPlot`with `PlotStyle`, e.g. `R = RegionPlot[
  y^2 - x (x - 1) (x - 3) < 0 && x < 2, {x, -2, 7}, {y, -4, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Yellow]`